# Visual Studio Multiple Monitors Laptop Docked to Undocked

Tags: visual-studio, layout, window, multiple-monitors

When I have my laptop docked, I like to have Visual Studio and it's sidebar windows spread across 2 monitors, so that I can have a maximized code view and all the supplementary windows over on the second monitor.  When I undock my laptop to work on the go, I obviously lose the 2 monitor advantage.  However, switching between 1 and 2 monitors is a rough experience, as window layouts get all screwed up or lost as you switch back and forth.

Anyone out there that works this way and as found a successful way to keep layouts as you dock and undock between 2 monitors and the laptop monitor?  I realize you probably can't have the exact same layout in both scenarios, but can VS be made smart enough to switch between 2 layout configurations or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to specify which OS you're running.

Comment: To clarify: As I've found out using VS on a laptop (with a 2nd monitor at work), Win7 is better at handling multiple monitors. So I'm asking for the __OS version__. That it must be Windows I was sure of.

Comment: Yes, it is Win 7 x64 in this case; I do think this problem does go beyond OS however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's what I do:**

1. Set up the environment windows as you want them on *each* of your two setups (multiple monitors and single laptop screen).
2. Using the "Import and Export Settings Wizard" (found in the Tools menu), choose to export only the "General Settings > Window Layouts" to files named for each configuration. Keep the files somewhere where they will always be handy.
3. Then, whenever you switch setups, use the "Import and Export Settings Wizard" to import the settings file that accurately describes your new setup. Visual Studio will rearrange the tool windows to the layout described in the settings file.

Unfortunately Visual Studio is not smart enough to handle this for you automatically (yet), so you still have to switch between the two layouts yourself. It's a bit of a hack, but it definitely works.

If you were feeling really adventurous (or frustrated), you could [write an extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885119.aspx) for Visual Studio to remember your window positions and/or automatically import the appropriate settings file. I'm confident that you and I are not the only ones who could put this to good use.

Comment: Count me in as a potential user!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio remembers 3 layouts - Normal, Full Screen and Debug. You can customize these the way you want and then you can use Normal/Full Screen to switch when you're docked/undocked. Little faster than importing settings.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio implies you're using Windows.  I used to use a product called [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) to help out with this.  Wish there was an equivalent for Mac.